# my imageviews are not behaving properly in the table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a table view loading in the below manner. If a condition is met I need to add a particular image above the `cell.imageview`. Also the images are coming in different dimensions. Below is my code can anybody point me in where i am going wrong.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
if(array==nil||[array count]==0)
{

}
else
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dicttable=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *head=[dicttable objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *type=[dicttable objectForKey:@"type"];

    NSString *imgUrl = [dicttable objectForKey:@"image"];;
    if(imgUrl!=nil)
    {
        if(![[ImageCache sharedImageCache] hasImageWithKey:imgUrl])
        { 
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage_icon.png"];
            NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell.imageView,imgUrl,@"noimage_icon.png",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],nil];
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateImageViewInBackground:) withObject:myArray];
            cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            cell.imageView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] getImagefromCacheOrUrl:imgUrl];
            cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            cell.imageView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,48,48);
            [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage_icon.png"];
    }
    if([type isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluel.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];

        cell.textLabel.text = head;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle1;
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wnew1.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];
        cell.textLabel.text = head;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.imageView addsubview:spclimage]

        cell.textLabel.text = head;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle1;
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];            
    }
}
return cell;
```

Here the problem is only in the last row the special image is adding. Not in all rows. Also the image view size is different in all the time the tableview is reloading?

Comment: thats jest an image cache methode where we r caching the images.thats all.nothing is happening more there.

Comment: @Rob its an appdelegate methode where we are storing the image to the cache and then updating the image.

Comment: @Rob thanks alot for that valuable last comment.so if i need to add that special image to all the cell can u help me in how to do that?

Comment: I've added an answer. The typical pattern is that you call a method that knows which `indexPath` for which you're retrieving an image, it will retrieve that image, and then check to see if the cell for that `indexPath` is still on screen, and if so, update the image accordingly. (As an aside, many tableview asynchronous image loading processes that you'll see here on S.O. neglect to check to make sure the cell is still visible. That's a critical step.)

Comment: @Rob thanks alot for your time.But my problem is still how to add an image to the existing cellimageview.As u r rightly saying when using addsubview in one cell it wil be removed from another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The `updateImageViewInBackground` seems suspect, as the name suggests that you're updating an image view, but you don't specify which cell you're updating.
2. I also see you doing a `addSubview:spclimage`. Obviously, if that `spclimage` was on another cell, as soon as you do `addSubview`, it will be removed from the previous location before being added to current cell. In fact, just the notion of adding an image as a subview of an existing imageview is curious.
3. If your cache doesn't have the image yet, I see where you're initializing the image with `noimage_icon.png`, but I don't see where you're actually updating the image view. You say `updateImageViewInBackground` is "then updating the image". Do you mean setting the `image` property for the `imageView` for this `cell` for this `indexPath`? Or maybe updating `spclimage`? If so, that's problematic.
4. The typical pattern (using `GCD`) for this would be:

   ```
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage_icon.png"];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       UIImage *image = ... // do whatever you need to do to get the image, load cache, etc.

       // ok, now that you have the image, dispatch the update of the UI back to the main queue

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           // because we're doing this asynchronously, make sure the cell is still
           // visible (it could have scrolled off and the cell was dequeued and
           // reused), so we're going to ask the tableview for the cell for that
           // indexPath, and it returns `nil` if it's not visible. This method is
           // not to be confused with the similarly named `UITableViewControllerDelegate`
           // method.

           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

           // if the image view is still visible, update it

           if (cell)
           {
               cell.imageView.image = image;
           }    
       });

   });
   ```